# Htaccess setenvif header defined

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I was trying to make correct ajax redirect, by apache. 
All request are going to index.php where they are routing, 
but i want to filer ajax request by defined header, 
and check it before php - via htaccess, and redirect to ajax.php.
I was reading manuals and test some days before, but this simple lang. is not so simple :(
Htaccess is looking like that:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/over/index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: you want those requests that have a custom HTTP header to be routed to a file other than `index.php`. Right?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, is there is any difference between redirect by htaccess and by php?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this HTTP header:

```
AjaxLoader:  Death
```

Now, for redirecting requests based on this header:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP:AjaxLoader}   ^Death$
rewriteRule  (?<!index\.php)(.*)  index.php    [L,QSA]
```